# CTE: Get all parents and all children in one statement

Tags: postgresql, cte, recursive

I have this working CTE example.

I can select all grand-parents and all children.

But how can I select all grand-parents and all children in one statement?

In this example I want Grandfather, Father, Son as output if I give "Father" as input.

I use PostgreSQL. But I think this question should be standard SQL.

Please correct me if I use PostgreSQL specific syntax.

```
DROP table if exists tree;

CREATE TABLE tree (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 name character varying(64) NOT NULL,
 parent_id integer REFERENCES tree NULL
);

insert into tree values (1, 'Grandfather', NULL);
insert into tree values (2, 'Father', 1);
insert into tree values (3, 'Son', 2);


-- -------------------------------------
-- Getting all children works  

WITH RECURSIVE rec (id) as
(
  SELECT tree.id, tree.name from tree where name='Father'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT tree.id, tree.name from rec, tree where tree.parent_id = rec.id

  

  )
SELECT *
FROM rec;

-- Result: 
--  id |  name  
-- ----+--------
--   2 | Father
--   3 | Son



-- -------------------------------------
-- Getting all parents works

WITH RECURSIVE rec (id) as
(
  SELECT tree.id, tree.name, tree.parent_id from tree where name='Father'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT tree.id, tree.name, tree.parent_id from rec, tree where tree.id = rec.parent_id
  )
SELECT id, name
FROM rec;

-- Result
-- id |    name     
-- ----+-------------
--  2 | Father
--  1 | Grandfather
```

Above is a simplified working example. The tree can be up to 100 level deep. There can be several level of ancestors above "Father" and several level of descendants below. I want all ancestors and all descendants.

Answer (score 30):

If you want all ancestors and all descendants, you can combine the two queries in one. Use the two CTEs and then a simple `UNION`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
    -- descendants 
    rec_d (id, name) AS
    (
      SELECT tree.id, tree.name FROM tree WHERE name = 'Father'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT tree.id, tree.name FROM rec_d, tree where tree.parent_id = rec_d.id
    ),
    --  ancestors
    rec_a (id, name, parent_id) AS
    (
      SELECT tree.id, tree.name, tree.parent_id FROM tree WHERE name = 'Father'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT tree.id, tree.name, tree.parent_id FROM rec_a, tree WHERE tree.id = rec_a.parent_id
    )
SELECT id, name FROM rec_a
UNION 
SELECT id, name FROM rec_d ;
```

If we haven't got any errors above, we can them improve it:

- change the final `UNION` to `UNION ALL` by putting the starting node(s) in only one of the CTEs.
- use `JOIN .. ON` instead of the implicit joins.
- fix mismatches between SELECT and CTE column lists.

The query becomes:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
    -- starting node(s)
    starting (id, name, parent_id) AS
    (
      SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent_id
      FROM tree AS t
      WHERE t.name = 'Father'          -- this can be arbitrary
    ),
    descendants (id, name, parent_id) AS
    (
      SELECT s.id, s.name, s.parent_id 
      FROM starting AS s
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent_id 
      FROM tree AS t JOIN descendants AS d ON t.parent_id = d.id
    ),
    ancestors (id, name, parent_id) AS
    (
      SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent_id 
      FROM tree AS t 
      WHERE t.id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM starting)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent_id 
      FROM tree AS t JOIN ancestors AS a ON t.id = a.parent_id
    )
TABLE ancestors
UNION ALL
TABLE descendants ;
```

Comment: I don't understand what the final query is meant to do - the output is the same as `select * from tree`

Comment: @baxx it depends on your starting point. It gives all ancestors and descendants, not necessarily the whole tree. If you start with the root of the tree, sure, it'll give all the tree as all nodes are descendants of the root. But try with a different starting point.